# how to set text in edittext but the text should not be visible in edittext

Tags: android

How to set text in edittext but the text should not be visible in edittext.

Code is given here

```
Edittext ed= (Edittext) findviewbyid(R.layout.ed1);
```

Comment: You can use EditText's setTag(yourTextString); to set any info.

Comment: no its not hint its text set by setText method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this also

```
    ed.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want to show your text in EditText then make use of tag methods available. This wont show text in `EditText`. You can set text by using `setTag(yourText)` method. You can get the tag info. again by using `getTag()` method.

Example :

Setting Tag :

```
editText.setTag("myhiddentext");
```

Retrieving Tag info. :

```
String text=editText.getTag();
```

**Note** : User wont be able to use this text even when user long presses on EditText.

Comment: ya doing but it will be done after 7 minutes because i have no reputation as i m new here